# Doubley list in c , trouble in print

Tags: c, list

I have problem when I try to print doubly linked list from head to tail. It goes to the somewhere in the middle and than starts from the beginning and so on. There is a  C code with functions "insert " and one function at the end("nadji blok") which is printing a list.  Focus on function "insert" and "nadji blok-(find block)".

```
#include "dodatno.h"
#include "algoritam.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct at {
    char ime_prezime[51];
    long pocetak_bloka;
    struct at *next, *before;
};
typedef struct at atom;

struct  st{
    struct at *head, *tail;
    char medijan[51];
} indeks;

int insert(char *ime_prezime, long pocetak_bloka)
{
    atom *new;
    if ((new = (atom*)malloc(sizeof(atom))))
    {
        strcpy(new->ime_prezime, ime_prezime);
        new->pocetak_bloka = pocetak_bloka;
        printf(" DODAJ U LISTU : %s \n", new->ime_prezime);   /* control */

        new->next = NULL;
        new->before = NULL;

        if (indeks.head == NULL)
        {
            indeks.head = new;
            indeks.tail = new;
        }
        else{
            indeks.tail->next = new;
            new->before = indeks.tail;
            indeks.tail = new;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void inicijaliziraj(FILE *ulaz)
{
    int i; long pocetak;
    struct stanovnik buff;
    for (i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        fseek(ulaz, i*sizeof(buff)*VELICINA, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&buff, sizeof(buff), 1, ulaz);
        /* printf(" FREAD : %s", buff.ime_prezime);*/
        fseek(ulaz, -1 * sizeof(buff), SEEK_CUR);
        pocetak = ftell(ulaz);
        DodajUListu(buff.ime_prezime, pocetak);
    }
    return;
}

long nadji_blok(char *ime_prezime, FILE *ulaz)
{
    struct stanovnik vel;
    atom *p = indeks.head;

    for (; p; p = p->next)
    {
        printf("%s\n ", p->ime_prezime);
        if (strcmp(ime_prezime, p->ime_prezime) < 0)
            /*   in this for loop it goes indefenetly */
        {
            return (p->pocetak_bloka) - (VELICINA*sizeof(vel));
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

char *izl_naziv()
{
    char *s = "indeksna_pretraga.rez";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need exactly?

Comment: in function "nadji blok " while i try to go trough the list (in for loop) it goes very long and it does not stop

Comment: it goes somewhere to the midle of the list and then starts again at the begining of the list... something is not good with the pointers and i dont know what...

Comment: You really should try to code in English when you plan to ask for help online.

Comment: You should initialized `indeks.head` and `indeks.tail` somewhere so you know it's `NULL` on the first call to `insert()` .  On your 2nd, 3rd, etc calls to `insert()`, I think you are over-writing `tail` repeatedly.  You should be finding the _real_ tail first and add the new value there so you chain things together properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've got a couple of issues here. The first is that

```
struct  st{
    struct at *head, *tail;
    char medijan[51];
} indeks;
```

should be

```
struct  st{
    struct at head, tail;
    char medijan[51];
} indeks;
```

because you want `head` and `tail` to be actual elements with their own `next` and `before` pointers.

Now you need to point `indeks.head` at `indeks.tail` in your code (some initialization code) like this:

```
indeks.head->next = &indeks.tail;
indeks.head->before = &indeks.tail;
indeks.tail->next = &indeks.head;
indeks.tail->before = &indeks.head;
```

Next, I would separate out the allocation of your 'new' object and the filling it in from the insertion into the list. It's just cleaner that way.

Now, when you want to insert you would do something like this:

```
void foo(char *ime_prezime, long pocetak_bloka)
{
    atom *new;

    if ((new = (atom*)malloc(sizeof(atom)))) {
        strcpy(new->ime_prezime, ime_prezime);
        new->pocetak_bloka = pocetak_bloka;
        printf(" DODAJ U LISTU : %s \n", new->ime_prezime);   /* control */
        insert(&indeks.head, new);
    }
}

void insert(atom *at_location, atom *element)
{
    element->next = at_location->next;
    element->before = element->next->before;
    element->next->before = element;
    at_location->next = element;
}
```

To print the list:

```
void print_list(void)
{
    atom *element;

    element = &indeks.head->next;

    while (element != &indeks.head) {
        // print whatever info
        element = element->next;
    }
}
```